# Table width is more than expected due to min width of cell(s) iText

Tags: itext7

I create a pdf document with table from a csv file. I set the width for each column when creating the table. But if the cell content exceeds the set width, the table width increases and it exceeds the pdf document size. Hence the right columns does not appear in the table in pdf document.

How to fix this so that my table must be enclosed inside the pdf document with all the columns visible ?

Comment: Your allegation *if the cell content exceeds the set width, the table width increases and it exceeds the pdf document size* doesn't correspond with my own experience. Can you share some code?

Comment: Tried the same with the csv having 15 columns with some junk values. And I gave the widths as Table table = new Table(new float[]{2,3,3,1,2,2,4,3,2,4,2,4,2,5,1});
        table.setWidthPercent(100);      http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-1#1726-c01e04_unitedstates.java

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ITextTableExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "/Users/administrator/Documents/restpdfs/samplecsv.pdf";
        String csvPath = "/Users/administrator/Documents/restpdfs/Premeier_League - Sheet1.csv";
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(filePath);
        PdfDocument pdf =  new PdfDocument(writer);
        PageSize page = new PageSize(842, 680);
        Document document = new Document(pdf, page);

        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
        PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);
        
        Table table = new Table(new float[]{1.5f, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2});
        table.setWidthPercent(100)
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvPath));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        process(table, line, bold, true);
        
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            process(table, line, font, false);
        }
        reader.close();
        document.add(table);  
        document.close();
    }

    private static void process(Table table, String line, PdfFont font, boolean isHeader) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        int columnNumber = 0;
        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            if(isHeader) {
                Cell cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                cell.setNextRenderer(new CellRenderer(cell));
                cell.setPadding(5).setBorder(new SolidBorder(Color.BLACK,0.5f));
                table.addHeaderCell(cell);
            } else {
                columnNumber++;
            Cell cell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph(tokenizer.nextToken()));
            cell.setFont(font).setBorder(new SolidBorder(Color.BLACK, 0.5f));
            switch (columnNumber) {
                case 4:
                    cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                default:
                    //cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
            }
            table.addCell(cell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the error completely it will be mentioned the error as There is no Writer associated with it so pass the PdfWriter object into Pdf Document object

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**